# NGINX setup for web returning default configuration when using suffix

Tags: nginx, vps, url

I have a VPS where I have several projects running. Some of them serve web pages (made with React) and others are REST API endpoints for some of those pages.

All is working. But I've added a new feature to one of those web pages that is not working. Namely, I have a URL that looks like this: `example.com/app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end` and that is serving the right files.

But now I need to access `example.com/app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end/some_data` and have it serve the same files as before. However, when I access that URL, it's instead serving the files for the default config, which is at `example.com/`.

I've enabled NGINX debugging but got nothing. The first mention of any kind of URL is the serving of the default page files already.

Here's an excerpt of my NGINX configuration, anonymized:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;

load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_stream_js_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;    # Regular web traffic
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/user/web/temporary_home_page/build;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {

        # serve static frontend first  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/default.d/app_with_front_end_only.conf:
location /app_with_front_end_only {

    alias /home/user/web/AppWithFrontEndOnly/web/app_with_front_end_only/build;

    # serve static frontend first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/default.d/app_with_front_and_back_end.conf:
location /app_with_front_and_back_end {

    alias /home/user/web/AppWithFrontAndBackEnd/build;

    # serve static frontend first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /app_with_front_and_back_end/api {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:99999;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/default.d/app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end.conf:
location /app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end {

    alias /home/user/web/AppWithFrontEndAndSharedBackEnd/build;

    # serve static frontend first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";
```

I have searched a bit and tried several variations of  `location /app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end` but none made a difference.

What is the missing configuration in order to make that work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only after posting I realized that I could have tried with URL search params instead. Will test it later.

Comment: The `location` blocks at the end of your configuration aren't inside any `server` block.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen They are. They are loaded by `include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;`, which is inside a `server` block. I suppose it's just `nginx -T` that breaks the nesting when printing.

Besides, I found out that it indeed works if I use URL search params instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame challenge: what if I use URL search params instead of a suffix? E.g. `example.com/app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end?some_data_key=some_data_value` instead of `example.com/app_with_front_end_and_shared_back_end/some_data`.

Indeed it works! The problem is that I had to post this question in order to reach this conclusion. Maybe I should delete this question, but I'm not certain.